# Can I print the sum of 1 to 10 without using loop in C?

Tags: c, sum

How can I print the summation of 1 to 10 without using any loop, case, switch, goto.

Comment: `printf("%i\n", 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10)`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic

Comment: By using math: (1+10)*10/2. Sum of an arithmetic sequence.

Comment: Offtopic: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: We don't know what topic you need help with.  Is it basic math?  printing? recursion?

Comment: Just print the number 55, surely you can do that?

Comment: Use recurence to call same function with decreased parameter each step until parameter is equals zero.

Answer (score 9):

To find the sum of a certain number of terms of an arithmetic sequence, use the formula `Sn = n(a1 + an) / 2`, where *S<sub>n</sub>* is the sum of *n* terms (*n*<sup>th</sup> partial sum),
*a*<sub>1</sub> is the first term, *a<sub>n</sub>* is the *n*<sup>th</sup> term. So you can write:

```
int n = 10;
int somme = n * (n + 1) / 2;
printf("%d", somme);
```

Reference: http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/atp2/arithseq.htm

Comment: Can you explain why this works?

Comment: @hosch250 This is the general formula for calculating the sum of a sequence where `An = An-1 + 1`

Comment: Full demo :
http://www.mathalino.com/reviewer/derivation-of-formulas/derivation-of-sum-of-arithmetic-progression
Or :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhah3xwVtSU

Comment: Please check code before upvoting.  At time of commenting, it says [`int somme = n(n+1) / 2;`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26415684/3) and has 3 upvotes. :-/   And that's all it says.  C'mon folks, three lines too hard to read?

Comment: @HaralanDobrev Yes, I know.  Apparently it was developed by Gauss.  What I meant was, the explanation should be in the body of the answer.

Comment: @HostileFork Really?  A variable can be named anything, can't it?  What does it matter as long as it compiles?

Comment: *What does it matter if it compiles?*  You don't multiply `n` by `n+1` implicitly by writing `n(n+1)` in C.  That's fine if you're giving a pseudocode answer in a language-agnostic fashion, because it can be understood from math.  But the question is about C, and if your answer is giving the facade of C enough to include printf in it, then I think legal syntax is indeed important in an answer...

Comment: @HostileFork Of course.  You mean you should explicitly call `n * (n + 1)`?

Comment: @HostileFork I made an edit. Please review.

Comment: Sorry, clearly my answer wasn't complete. Thanks for editing

Answer (score 1):

Use recurrence: calculate sub result until you hit 0 and then return final result.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using recursion.  Pass the highest limit, the lowest limit, and 0 to `SumNum`, and it will print the sum of the numbers 1 through `high`.  What it does is add the number `high` to `sum`, which you initialized to 0, then calls the function again with `high - 1` for `high`:

```
void SumNum(int high, int low, int sum)
{
    if (high == low) {
        printf("%i\n", sum);
        return;
    }
    else SumNum(high - 1, low, sum + high);
}

int main()
{
    SumNum(10, 0, 0);
}
```

I am not sure if this is optimal C because I mainly use C++.  I prefer the C++ version, where you just pass `high` and `low` from `main()` without passing the starting sum of 0 too:

```
void SumNum(int high, int low, int sum = 0)
{
    if (high == low) {
        printf("%i\n", sum);
        return;
    }
    else SumNum(high - 1, low, sum + high);
}

int main()
{
    SumNum(10,0);
}
```